# Bootstrap menudropdown show in the background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello Everybody
I'm beginner with bootstrap library and in my html page, when the cursors is on **"Item 2"**, the menu is show in the background.
I don't want use the dropdown from library bootstrap :) 
I would like use a custom menu dropdown :) 
I don't know where is located the problem.

Here the source code 
[Demo](http://jsbin.com/lezejepadu/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is surely to set the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of the dropdown item

Comment: Thank you Julian Berger your answer it very helpfull for me !

Comment: you're welcome [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) is a really nice resource for all the web-dev-stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Where you have your #menuDropdown ul li:hover ul, you need to set the z-index to something higher than default (which is 0).

```
 #menuDropdown ul li:hover ul {
     display:block;
     z-index: 2;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips !

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following to css.

```
#menuDropdown li {
 /* ... */
 position: relative;
 z-index: 50;
}
```

Your [Demo edited](http://jsbin.com/tutenuneqo/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: Thank you KmeCnin for your answer it works thanks for your help !

Comment: Cool. Now, please choose any of the 3 answers, the one you think will could help the more the next viewer of the page. All are goods, just pick your favorit.